# Powershell | Stuck in while loop

Tags: powershell, loops, while-loop

I have a small script that checks the communication date of the mcafee agent:

```
$GetLastCommunication = & "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent" -i | Select-String -Pattern LastASCTIME | Out-String
$GetLastCommunication = $GetLastCommunication.Replace("`n", "").Replace("`r", "").Replace(" ","")

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $newagentdir = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse "\\IP\Downloads\" -Include "FramePkg.exe").FullName
    $arg = "/forceinstall /install=agent /silent"
    Copy-Item -Path $newagentdir -Destination $env:TEMP
    Start-Process -Wait $env:TEMP\FramePkg.exe -ArgumentList $arg
}

while ($GetLastCommunication = "LastASCTime:N/A"){
    sleep -Seconds 5
}

Reload-Form
```

after the installation, the LastASCTime line changes automatically from "N/A" to the time of communication, after 15 to 20 seconds.

I need for him to reload the form when the LastASCTime line changes from N/A to the comm time.
Currently, is getting stuck in the while loop and doesn’t reload the form.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: `=` is for assignment, if you want to test for equality, use `-eq`

Comment: I changed to: while ($GetLastCommunication -eq "LastASCTime:N/A") but still freezes

Comment: Your loop will either never be entered or forever.

Comment: You're looping based on the value of a variable that never changes.  Try copying the two `$GetLastCommunication = ...` lines that begin your code snippet to the end of the body of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially...

```powershell
$lastKnownState = Get-SomeState

while ($lastKnownState -eq $operationInProgressState)
{
    sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Your loop is waiting 5 seconds between checking if the operation has completed, but because `$lastKnownState` is just a *snapshot* of the operation's state and not modified inside the loop, the loop will never terminate.

Instead, you need to actually refresh the state after the timeout...

```powershell
$lastKnownState = Get-SomeState

while ($lastKnownState -eq $operationInProgressState)
{
    sleep -Seconds 5

    $lastKnownState = Get-SomeState
}
```

In your code, after correcting the [`=` assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators) to the [`-eq` comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#-eq-and--ne), that would look like this...

```powershell
while ($GetLastCommunication -eq "LastASCTime:N/A"){
    sleep -Seconds 5

    $GetLastCommunication = & "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent" -i | Select-String -Pattern LastASCTIME | Out-String
    $GetLastCommunication = $GetLastCommunication.Replace("`n", "").Replace("`r", "").Replace(" ","")

}
```

Also, instead of chaining calls to `Replace()` with...

```powershell
$GetLastCommunication = $GetLastCommunication.Replace("`n", "").Replace("`r", "").Replace(" ","")
```

...you can use the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) with a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) that will match and remove `CR`, `LF`, or space characters...

```powershell
$GetLastCommunication = $GetLastCommunication -replace '[\r\n ]'
```

Those characters are being [escaped for the .NET regular expression engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions) and not PowerShell, which is why backslashes are used instead of backticks.  If what you really want to do is match `LF` optionally preceded by a `CR` (i.e. `CRLF` or `LF`) that can be matched with [`\r?\n`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-zero-or-one-time-)...

```powershell
$GetLastCommunication = $GetLastCommunication -replace '\r?\n| '
```